# Functions: domain, codomain, range and graph

Tags: functions

I have a question in my course.

Let $A = \{0, 1\}$, $B = \{4, 5, 6, 7\}$ and $C = \mathbb{N}$ (natural numbers). Consider the following functions:

$f:A\to B$ s.t. $f(x) = x+5$

$g:B\to C$ s.t. $g(x) = 2x−2$

$h:C \to A$ s.t. $h(x) = \begin{cases}
                                   0 & \text{if $x < 10$} \\
                                   1 & \text{if $x \ge 10$} \\
  \end{cases}$

Which of the following compositions are defined?
If they are defined, compute their domain, codomain, range and graph.

**(a)** $f \circ g$

**(b)** $g \circ f$

**(c)** $h \circ g$

**(d)** $g\circ h$

My answer:

•   Domain of $f$ is $A = \{0, 1\}$; domain of $g$ is $B = \{4,5,6,7\}$; domain of $h$ is $C = \mathbb{N}$;

•   Codomain of $f$ is $B = \{4,5,6,7\}$; codomain of $g$ is $C = \mathbb{N}$; codomain of $h$ is $A = \{0,1\}$.

•   Range of $f$ is $\{5, 6\}$; range of $g$ is $\{4,8,10,12\}$; range of $h$ is $\{0,1\}$.

**a)** $f \circ g = f(g(x)) = 2x + 5 -2 = 2x + 3$

**b)** $g \circ f = g(f(x)) = 2(x + 5) – 2 = 2x + 8$

**c)** $h \circ g = -2 \text{ if } x < 10;\ h \circ g = 0 \text{ if } x \ge 10 $

**d)** $g \circ h = g(h(x)) = -2\text{ if } x < 10; g \circ h = 0 \text{ if } x \ge 10$

Could I please get a review and how to calculate the graph?

Comment: You need to check whether the compositions are even defined before you develop formulas for them.  Also, the range of $g$ is $\{6, 8, 10, 12\}$.  Note that $g(4) = 2 \cdot 4 - 2 = 6$.

Comment: how can i check if the compositions are defined? 
ah, thanks for the comment. I missed the 6!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The composite function $f \circ g$ is only defined if the codomain of $g$ is contained in the domain of $f$.  Depending on the definition you are using, you may need the stronger condition that the codomain of $g$ equals the domain of $f$.

In this case, the codomain of $g$ is $\mathbb{N}$ and the domain of $A = \{0, 1\}$.  Moreover, as noted in the comments, since the range of $g$ is $\{6, 8, 10, 12\}$, the elements in the range of $g$ are not contained in the domain of $f$.  Thus, the composite function $f \circ g$ is undefined.

Since $f: A \to B$ and $g: B \to C$, the composite function $g \circ f$ is defined since the codomain of $f$ equals the domain of $g$.  As you correctly concluded, the function $g \circ f: A \to C$ is defined by
$$(g \circ f)(x) = g(f(x)) = g(x + 5) = 2(x + 5) - 2 = 2x + 8$$
The graph of the composite function $g \circ f$ is the set of all ordered pairs $(a, c) \in A \times C$ such that $(g \circ f)(a) = c$ for some $a \in A$.  Since $(g \circ f)(0) = 8$ and $(g \circ f)(1) = 10$, the graph of the function $g \circ f$ is the set
$$G_{g \circ f} = \{(0, 8), (1, 10)\}$$

Since $g: B \to C$ and $h: C \to A$, the composite function $h \circ g$ is defined since the codomain of $g$ equals the domain of $h$.  Since $h: C \to A$ is defined by
$$h(x) = \begin{cases}
         0 & \text{if $x < 10$}\\
         1 & \text{if $x \geq 10$}
         \end{cases}
$$
and $g: B \to C$ is defined by $g(x) = 2x - 2$, observe that if $x \in B$, then
$$(g \circ h)(x) = \begin{cases}
                    0 & \text{if $x < 6$}\\
                    1 & \text{if $x \geq 6$}
                   \end{cases}
$$
To see this, observe that if $x < 6$, $g(x) = 2x - 2 < 2 \cdot 6 - 2 = 10$, and that if $x \geq 6$, $g(x) = 2x - 2 \geq 2 \cdot 6 - 2 = 10$.  Since
\begin{align*}
(h \circ g)(4) & = h(g(4)) = h(6) = 0\\
(h \circ g)(5) & = h(g(5)) = h(8) = 0\\
(h \circ g)(6) & = h(g(6)) = h(10) = 1\\
(h \circ g)(7) & = h(g(7)) = h(12) = 1
\end{align*}
the graph of $h \circ g$ is
$$G_{h \circ g} = \{(4, 0), (5, 0), (6, 1), (7, 1)\}$$

Observe that $h: C \to A$ and $g: B \to C$, so the codomain of $h$ is not contained in the domain of $g$ since $A$ is not a subset of $B$.  Thus, the composite function $g \circ h$ is not defined.

Comment: thank you, very well answered! I can read well and understand the procedure.

Comment: so the codomain of f is B{4,5,6,7} ?

Comment: Yes, as you yourself wrote, the codomain of $f$ is $B$, the codomain of $g$ is $C$, and the codomain of $h$ is $A$.  When you write the function $f: A \to B$ defined by ..., that means the domain of $f$ is $A$ and the codomain of $f$ is $B$.  The rule defining the function $f$ determines its range, which must be a subset of the codomain.

Comment: not sure why :→ is defined by ()=2−2, observe that if ∈, then
(∘ℎ)()={0 if <6; 1 if ≥6}. Where does 6 comes from?

Comment: ah, ok, you take 6 as it is the lowest value in B range.